# How to access custom setting url field in apex?

Tags: apex, customsetting

How to access custom setting url field in apex.In my class i have a link in success message "Create Record". when user click the link it 
will diplay the site page.My problem is how to access the url field in herf link.

Now i have use below code in my class

```
successMsg ='Please click the link to create more records -a href="http://test-site.cs18.force.com/Account" <font size="3px"><b>Create Record</b></font></a>' ;
```

Now i have trying the below code but im not getting the solution.

```
successMsg ='Please click the link to create more records -a href="{!$Setup.AccountURL__c.Url__c}" <font size="3px"><b>Create Cases</b></font></a>' ;
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the HTML in an ApexPages.Message rendered as HTML the default escaping must be turned off in the Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
```

and values of hierarchy custom settings can be [accessed in Apex code](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_System_HierarchyCustomSetting_getInstance) like this:

```
String s = 'Message with <a href="' + AccountURL__c.getInstance().Url__c + '">link</a>';
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, s);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply im using this code but im getting visualforce error.So i have check the debug log, string value its shows null.

Comment: Have clicked the "Manage" button for the setting and "New" and set a value for the Url field and clicked "Save"?